# HTML/CSS element that randomly changes height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I intend for the footer of my page to be one line tall.
Sometimes when I open my page in a new window/tab, the footer is two lines tall.  If I reload within a tab, it looks fine.

My page is [here](http://www.dine-o.com/tos)

The relevant portion of the page is near the bottom

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="logo">&#169; 2013 Dine-O</div>
    <div class="pull-right"><a href="/signup/restaurant"> Restaurant Signup </a> | <a href="/apps"> Apps </a> | <a href="/tos"> Terms </a> | <a href="/privacy"> Privacy </a></p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Sometimes the #logo and .pull-right divs are on the same line.  Sometimes they appear on different lines.

The "bug" only happens when loading the page on a new tab.  Anyone have suggestions on why I'm getting this random behavior?

Comment: Does it happens in all browsers? or in a specific one?
Is there a style that you apply using javascript at load time?

Comment: Chrome user here, seems to work as expected. Could you make a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of it?

Comment: Thanks for trying folks.  It happens in Chrome, randomly.  Sometimes it loads up just fine.  I usually have to create a new window, attempt to load the page.  Usually it's bad once every 5 tries or so.  If I re-use a window, it's usually good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must say that is a WEIRD bug. Notice it only happens in chrome too.

I believe it will be fixed if you add:

```
#logo {
float: left;
}
```

It looks like your div is clearing the `".pull_right"` which it kinda should be since `footer`
inherits clealrfix in bootstrap. I must say I have no idea why it happens ONLY on new tabs.

Comment: WebKit (and now Blink) have rendering bugs like this frighteningly often. Until the Chrome team came along, proper testing seems to have been almost non-existent, and they have only improved the situation—not fixed it by a long shot. I tend to find that Chrome has notably debilitating bugs at least once every few releases, while Firefox has only in one (which they then released a fix for a couple of days later).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan This is interesting. Do you have more info on this?  (links )

Comment: sorry, not handy; I've wished that I kept a register of them, but I haven't done so and they don't tend to be easy things to track down. That makes it purely anecdotal.

Comment: I have also found firefox to be much better lately. I must say I _thought_ I am quite familiar with CSS especially in Chrome but I haven't encountered such bugs. Any resource would be extremely helpful and interesting, Even if it's a screenshot

Comment: The most recent thing I've had is a page in development where three boxes which should have been adjacent being stacked on top of one another in Chrome on page load, until *any* CSS property is changed—then it would render it correctly. But then with that I've changed the structure quite a bit to avoid that, so I have no documentation of that any more either... amusingly, it tends to be the goal when you hit such cases of bad rendering to destroy all the evidence.